# How to make a demo JHipster with H2 embedded for 'production'

Tags: h2, jhipster

I've used JHipster 3.12.2 (Spring Boot) with H2 (disk, not memory) to develop a small demo app (3 or 4 entity tables, a half dozen of most entities, and 48 images embedded as ImageBlobs in the database, as generated using JHipster JDL). When I generated the app I selected Postgresql as the production database, since H2 isn't a choice ... but I've run into some problem with the dockerized version (it's really slow, need to put Docker on his machine, need to figure out how to re-initialize data, etc) so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to just embed H2 as my "production" DB for this? (And then I could reuse the CSV files and data loading scripts I used in development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's as easy as copying the `datasource` and `jpa` relevant configurations from application-dev.yml into application-prod.yml, to point tell it should load h2 drivers instead of psql.

However I would not suggest to take h2 as real production, as there is a lack of management tools to this database, as h2 isn't used to be choosen for that. If you are not using Postgres, you still can switch to mysql for production, if that fits better your needs.

Comment: I see I edited out an important note - my "production" here is just running the standalone app on one guy's laptop for a UX demo, so management, security etc don't apply. That said, what you suggest works - with a caveat.

What I discovered with JHipster is odd: if you know you're going to want H2 in the production profile, start with MSSQL, not Postgres. When I start with MSSQL I can do as you suggest (and I remove the MSSQL driver dependency from pom.xml); but if I start with Postgres, doing that gives me a "duplicated [hibernate_sequence]" error and the integration tests all fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete David answer:

from application-dev:

1-datasource

> ```
> uri : 
>   jdbc:h2:mem:yourapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=LEGACY
> ```

2- h2

> ```
> console:  
>   enabled: true
> ```

3- jpa

> ```
> liquibase:
>   contexts: prod, faker
> ```